# Eigenvalue and Eigenvector used in statistics

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find how eigenvalues and eigenvectors are used in statistics. I found  this :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis

Eigenvalues can be used in Factor analysis. However I would like to know if eigenvalues and eigenvector can be used in Stats in any other topic.

Can anyone help me on this or recommend a website to read about this?

Thanks

Comment: For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Answer (score 0):

In statistical pattern recognition, one often pre-processes high-dimensional data by projecting it onto a subspace defined by the $k$ vectors with largest (magnitude) eigenvalues, as these capture the largest variation in the data (principal component analysis).  See Chapter 10, ***[Pattern classification](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471056693)*** (2nd ed.) or ***[Pattern recognition and machine learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738)***.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will take a look.

Comment: I don't like spam.

Comment: A reference is not spam.  Another reference has been added.

Comment: A reference to your book about a common topic that is covered by thousands of other sources *is* spam